# vc++ - socket is not writing into the port

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sockets, ftp-client

I am trying to create a ftp client with uploading a file capability. But the socket is not sending the message into the server, even though it got the connection with the server. See the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc,wchar_t * argv[])
{

    WSADATA wsaData = {0};
    int iResult = 0;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET sock= socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error = %d\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    else
        std::wcout << " Success occured in socket creation " << std::endl ;

    SOCKADDR_IN sock_Addr={0};
    sock_Addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sock_Addr.sin_port=htons(21);
    sock_Addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.105");

    char recv_Buf[1000]={'\0'};
    if(connect(sock,(SOCKADDR *)&sock_Addr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) != 0)
        std::cout << " Error in connection " << std::endl ;
    else
    {
        std::string tmp;
        u_long mode =1; // non blocking socket
        ioctlsocket(sock,FIONBIO,&mode);
        int result = recv(sock,recv_Buf,sizeof(recv_Buf),0);
        while( result > 0 )
        {
            tmp=tmp+recv_Buf;
            result = recv(sock,recv_Buf,sizeof(recv_Buf),0);
        }
        std::cout << "connection - success - " << tmp << std::endl ;
    }

    ioctlsocket(sock,FIONBIO,0);
    std::string buf="USER administrator";
    if(send(sock,buf.c_str(),buf.size(),0)== SOCKET_ERROR)
    std::cout << " sending user - error  " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl ;
    else
    {
        std::string tmp;
        u_long mode =1; // non blocking socket
        ioctlsocket(sock,FIONBIO,&mode);
        int result = recv(sock,recv_Buf,sizeof(recv_Buf),0);
        while( result > 0 )
        {
            tmp=tmp+recv_Buf;
            result = recv(sock,recv_Buf,sizeof(recv_Buf),0);
            std::cout << "received " << recv_Buf << std::endl ;
        }
        std::cout << "user - success - " << tmp << std::endl ;
    }
}
```

Note : I am using [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) To check this . It will show the incoming connections and the commands. 
      So if anybody guide me in this issue, I will be thankful to you.

**Edit**
   Below is the client side(my side) command prompt result

*Success occured in socket creation*

*connection - success - 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.37 beta*

*220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)*

*220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/*

*user - success -*

*Press any key to continue . . .*

This one was displayed at the server side

(000007)5/17/2011 23:32:02 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.105)> Connected, sending welcome message...

(000007)5/17/2011 23:32:02 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.105)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.37 beta

(000007)5/17/2011 23:32:02 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.105)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)

(000007)5/17/2011 23:32:02 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.105)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/

(000007)5/17/2011 23:32:02 PM - (not logged in) (10.0.0.105)> disconnected.

Comment: I haven't looked that closely at your code, but FTP commands are terminated by a carriage return - line feed pair (\r\n).  I don't see that in your USER command string.

Comment: @Peter Wow, you exactly told the point. Give this comment as answer, then only I can vote for it.

Comment: @prabhakaran: done.  I actually wrote an FTP server nearly 20 years ago.  Ah memories :).

Comment: Not about what you're looking for, but your code has a serious problem in handling of reading. If the first read from the socket is longer than the second you will update your tmp variable with the wrong content. Also you will have problems reading NULs with this kind of code. The correct approach is `tmp += std::string(recv_Buf, recv_Buf+result);` using all and only the characters you got back from `recv`.

Comment: @6502 thank you for your guidance. After I saw your advice I checked the characters, and I found that it has two \0 values at the end.

Comment: @6502 Thank you for your suggestion. It saved a lot time for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP commands are terminated by a carriage return - line feed pair (\r\n).  You need to add \r\n to your USER command string.

Edit: you should consult [RFC 959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) for more information (there's more FTP-related RFCs that update and extend RFC 959 too).  It has a section detailing the base FTP commands and shows the expected format, including <CRLF> pair.